# Extract tabular data from GeoTiff files

Tags: python, raster, tiff

I imported data from https://daac.ornl.gov/DAYMET/guides/Daymet_V3_Monthly_Climatology.html which promises minimum and maximum temperature, precipitation, and vapor pressure for different locations. As far as I understand, these values value nothing without their geolocations (which seems the concept of raster formats (tif...)). Now I want to get tabular data, from locations I want to get values: minimum and maximum temperature, precipitation, and vapor pressure. I really have no entry point except I manage to read raster files in Python but it seems to provide only images.

```
import rasterio
dataset = rasterio.open('raster_extensions/daymet_climatology_data/daymet_v3_prcp_monttl_2018_pr.tif')
dataset.count

from rasterio.plot import show
show(dataset.read(1))
```

Tabular data are directly consumable by pandas to do statistical analysis on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, can you clarify things?

Comment: along with images which to my understanding called bands, I want get other tabular data,  that seems to be time indexed, that represents numeric values of  minimum and maximum temperature, precipitation, and vapor pressure